# How to resolve WinError 87 running py2exe on Win 10

Tags: python, py2exe

Even my test case is exhibiting this error.

Contents of test.py are:

```
print("Hello World")
```

setup2.py is:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['test.py'])
```

When I run cmd as administrator and attempt to run 'python setup2.py py2exe' I get the following:

```
>python setup2.py py2exe
running py2exe

  2 missing Modules
  ------------------
? _posixshmem                         imported from multiprocessing.resource_tracker, multiprocessing.shared_memory
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
Building 'dist\test.exe'.
error: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect.
```

Build environment is:
Windows 10 Version 20H2 with all the latest updates
Python 3.8.6
py2exe 0.10.4.0

Any ideas on how to resolve this error?

I've seen one clue that it has something to do with unicode characters and was solved with simpleprint but am unsure how to implement that

Comment: Fun discovery: The above sample code works fine on Windows 10 IoT Version 1809 with Python 3.9.  But I really have no idea why

Comment: Looks like this was listed as py2exe issue and is thought to be Windows version specific: https://github.com/py2exe/py2exe/issues/76

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've actually stumbled on a better solution.  I was able to get py2exe to work correctly on both versions of Windows 10 by installing from the downloaded installer from Python.org.

When using a Python install from the Windows Store, that was when I was encountering the issue.  Using Python from an installer, and it seems to work

Answer (score 1):

I'm not real happy with the fix, but I've stumbled on a way to fix this issue.

I'm guessing this is Windows version specific based on discoveries here:
https://github.com/py2exe/py2exe/issues/76

I was able to get everything to work as expected on Win 10 IoT Version 1809 with Python 3.9

When attempting to run the resulting *.exe's, I kept getting errors about module packaging.version not found.  That was fixed based on this answer:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2162

By adding the following imports to the main *.py file (test.py in the example I originally posted)

```
import packaging
import packaging.version
import packaging.specifiers
import packaging.requirements
```